# web2py: crud form custom widget conditional show/hide

Tags: web2py

I'm using custom widget in my crud form like this:

```
{{=form.custom.begin}}
{{if condition:}}
    {{=form.custom.widget.field1}}
{{pass}}
{{=form.custom.submit}}
{{=form.custom.end}}
```

field1 has a relationship to the auth_user table. In my controller I have:

```
form.custom.widget['field1'] = dropdown

if not condition:
    db.admission.field1.readable = db.admission.field1.writable = False
    db.admission.field1.default = auth.user.id
```

I want the widget to show only when the condition is true. If the condition is not true, I want field1 to default to the current logged-in user. But, when the condition is not true, I get the error:

```
field1 error: value not in database
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `readable` and `writable` attributes before creating the form -- in that case, `field1` will simply be excluded from the form automatically, and you won't have to bother with creating a custom form and explicitly including/excluding it.